# How to fix an image being blurry when rendered with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image-size

I received some feedback about a past assignment warning me about my images being blurry. But I can't figure out how to fix it. The assignment gives very clear descriptions of what to do but I did everything it asked.

I have to do the following for the images:

> Add a new selector id named yurthero. In CSS code declarations to configure 300px height and to display the coast.jpg background image to fill the space(use background-size: 100% 100%;) without repeating.

How can I stop my image from being blurry? It seems to me that the stretching forces it to blur.

Attached below is the html5, the css3, and the image I am using. [image: coast.jpg]

```css
/* pacific.css for assignment #3 by Caleb Latimer */
body{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      color : #666666;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-image: url(background.jpg);
}
h1{
      background-color: #000033;
      color : #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Georgia;
      line-height: 200%;
      background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-left: 20px;
      height: 72px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-position: right;
}
nav{
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #90C7E3;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
h2{
      color: #3399CC;
      font-family: Georgia;
}
dt{
      color: #000033;
      font-weight: bold;
}
.resort{
      color: #000033;
      font-size: 1.2em;
}
footer{
      font-size: .70em;
      font-style: italic;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#wrapper{
      width: 80%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      min-width: 700px;
      max-width: 1024px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}
h3{
      color: #000033;
}
main{
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      display:block;
}
#homehero{
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(coast.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#yurthero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#trailhero{
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url(trail.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
nav a{
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Chapter 4 Homework by Caleb Latimer -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css" /> <!-- Uses the pacific.css stylesheet inside of folder -->
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
             <header>
                     <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
             </header>

          <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> 
            &nbsp;
            <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a> <!-- Doesn't lead anywhere no requirements given -->
          </nav>

          <div id ="homehero"></div>
          <main>
            <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>

            <p>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.
            </p>

            <ul>
              <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
              <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
              <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
              <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
              <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
            </ul>

            <div>
              <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br />
              12010 Pacific Trails Road <br />
              Zephyr, CA 95555<br /><br />
              888-555-5555<br />
            </div>

          </main>

          <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort <br />
            <a href = "mailto:Caleb@Latimer.com">Caleb@Latimer.com</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out I was given the wrong pictures for the assignment. With the correct pictures they turn out as intended. Always check size, height and width dimensions on images.